# Application crashes when given big number

Tags: java, android, long-integer

I created an app that generate random number between 2 given values and and its working good it dose what it say but if i entered 11 digit number in the max value (or min value) the app crashes how can I fix it is there another way to generate random number to support big values here is the code

```
        Button gen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText mini = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mini);
        final EditText maxi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.maxi);
        final TextView res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        final Random r = new Random();
        final int[] number = {0};

        gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                int minn = Integer.parseInt(mini.getText().toString());
                int maxx = Integer.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());

                if (minn>=maxx){
                   maxi.setText(String.valueOf(minn));
                   mini.setText(String.valueOf(maxx));
                   maxx = Integer.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());
                   minn = Integer.parseInt(mini.getText().toString());
                   number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);
                   res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
               }else{
                   number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);
                   res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
               }
               getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            }   
       });
}
```

Comment: Use double or long instead of Integer.

Comment: what does this have to do with `admob`?

Comment: Your two questions are totally unrelated. Don't mix them up in one post. Furthermore, the ads question is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use long or double instead of Integer. Because Integer doesn't support that much large value.

```
long minn = Long.parseInt(mini.getText().toString());
           long maxx = Long.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());
```

or

```
double minn = Double.parseInt(mini.getText().toString());
               double maxx = Double.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());
```

Comment: number[0] = minn + r.nextLong(maxx - minn + 1); ---> nextLong( ) 
in Random cannot be applied
to
(long)

Comment: what is nextLong(). If it a function then check that it return's long value or not?

Answer (score 2):

Set minn and maxx variables to **long**.

**Integer:**

- MAX VALUE =  2147483647
- MIN VALUE = -2147483648

**Long:**

- MAX VALUE =  9223372036854775807
- MIN VALUE = -9223372036854775808

Find out more:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

This is occuring because the Integer class doesn't support values that large. Try using Longs or Floats. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

The max value of int is  2,147,483,647

use long if you need higher values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate on really big numbers, use BigInteger instead.Integer can't handle big numbers and that's the reason why it's failing for you.